# Exception handling , unable to understand :(

Tags: c++, exception

Hya advance users of SO,

First of all I am new to C++, so pardon me if I don't make myself clear asking question. I've seen a example of exception handling, but couldn't figure out what's happening here :(

http://codepaste.net/zqsrnj
or

```
enum ErrorCode {…}; // this is exception class
ErrorCode dispatcher() {
   try {
      throw; // what is thrown here in function?, if rethrow what is rethrown?
   }
   catch (std::bad_alloc&) {
      return ErrorCode_OutOfMemory;
   }
   catch (std::logic_error&) {
      return ErrorCode_LogicError;
   }
   catch (myownstdexcderivedclass&) {
      return ErrorCode_42;
   }
   catch(...) { // this will handle the above throw in try block of dispatcher
      return ErrorCode_UnknownWeWillAllDie;
   }
}

ErrorCode apifunc() {
   try {
      // foo() might throw anything
      foo();
   }
   catch(...) {
      // dispatcher rethrows the exception and does fine-grained handling
      return dispatcher();
   }
   return ErrorCode_Fine; // 
}

ErrorCode apifunc2() {
   try {
      // bar() might throw anything
      bar();
   }
   catch(...) {
      return dispatcher();
   }
   return ErrorCode_Fine;
}
```

Can anyone explain this line by line or overall what's happening here, how control is flowing? Any help is very much appreciated, so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apifunc()` and `apifunc2()` translate exceptions into error codes, using the `dispatcher()` function.

Basically, what happens is as follows:
`apifunc()` (and similarly `apifunc2()`) attempts to call a function `foo()`. If `foo()` throws an exception, then the `catch` block will call `dispatcher()` to get the error code corresponding to the exception, and then returns that error code. If `foo()` doesn't throw, `apifunc()` returns `ErrorCode_Fine` indicating no error.

`dispatcher()` works by re-throwing the last exception thrown, i.e. the one `foo()` threw. `dispatcher()` then checks which exception was thrown using the `catch` blocks, and returns the correct error code. For example, if `foo()` threw `std::bad_alloc`, then that catch-block will be executed and return `ErrorCode_OutOfMemory;`.

**Why would someone do this?**

Exceptions are not necessarily binary compatible across different compilations (compilers, compiler flags, and so on), so translating exceptions to error codes is more portable across module boundaries.

Comment: `ErrorCode dispatcher() {   try {      throw; // what is thrown here in function?, if rethrow what is rethrown?   }`   when dispatcher is called whats it throwing since this function didn't get any parameter

Comment: If there's an exception currently propagating, it just rethrows this exception. If there isn't, it calls `std::terminate`. Imagine your function `foo()` threw `std::bad_alloc`, `catch (...)` block is entered and `dispatcher()` is called. `throw;` rethrows the bad_alloc exception and enters apropriate catch block.

Comment: Thanks vitus for your supportive and helpful comments. you should have also answered the question. Thanks also to both answerers i appreciate your effort to make me understand this weird thing.

Answer (score 1):

When `foo()` throws an exception during its execution, the exception is caught in the `apifunc()` wrapper whose catch clause invoke the `dispatcher()` method. There the "current" exception is rethrown (that's the empty `throw` statement in the `dispatcher()` method) and caught again. Then the different catch clauses (bad_alloc, logic_error, myownstdexcderivedclass ... returns a sepcific error code than will be returned to the outside world.

The last `catch(...)` clause ensures that **no exception will ever be thrown to the callers** of `apifunc()`.

Comment: so when exception is caught in apifunc, it calls dispatcher function . which rethrows by throw. what i am unable to understand is scope of thrown object by foo is visible in called function dispatcher?? but catch in apifunction catches the exception by (...) so how dispatcher will come to know what is type of thrown object. I am so confused please help

Comment: Thrown exceptions do not have automatic storage duration, their lifetime is determinted at run-time (i.e. exception lives until it was caught and not rethrown). `dispatcher()` can select apropriate `catch` block, because exceptions carry information about their type with them.

Comment: @Vitus : Please tell me what i think is right ,so when apifunc's catch catches the exception. and when it calls dispatcher , the scope of thrown object is visible in dispatcher since dispatcher was called from catch(...) of apifunc() . Thanks again vitus )